# What is the best way to represent closed days (holidays) using Schema.org vocabulary?

Tags: google-search, microdata, schema.org

At this point in time there's no property in Schema.org that would allow a business to directly communicate holiday periods (e.g., Christmas) to Google bots and other web crawlers. There seems to be an [open issue on Schema.org's GitHub repository](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/245) however there's no telling when or if something will get added.

I have seen two solutions to this issue so far:

1. Use `openingHoursSpecification` without `opens` and `closes` properties.

   ```html
   <p property="openingHoursSpecification" typeof="OpeningHoursSpecification">
       Closed between <time datetime="2015-12-24" property="validFrom">24th of December</time> and <time datetime="2015-12-26" property="validThrough">26th of December</time>.
   </p>
   ```

   This seems like a nice solution but do we have any evidence that Google bots will properly understand this? It seems to validate in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool but does that mean that `opens` and `closed` properties are not required by Google?
2. Use `openingHoursSpecification` with equal `opens` and `closes` properties.

   ```html
   <p property="openingHoursSpecification" typeof="OpeningHoursSpecification">
       Closed between <time datetime="2015-12-24" property="validFrom">24th of December</time> and <time datetime="2015-12-26" property="validThrough">26th of December</time>.
       <meta content="00:00:00" property="opens" />
       <meta content="00:00:00" property="closes" />
   </p>
   ```

   Again a nice solution but there seems to be little to no evidence of web crawlers correctly understanding this and not treating this as incorrect markup. Also it seems a bit illogical to have to specify that a business is open for zero seconds.

The only other solution I can think of to use `openingHoursSpecification` with `validFrom` and `validThrough` properties to specify all time frames seperatly (even when the default opening hours are valid).

```html
<div property="openingHoursSpecification" typeof="OpeningHoursSpecification">
    <meta content="10:00:00" property="opens" />
    <meta content="18:00:00" property="closes" />
    <meta content="2015-12-23" property="validThrough" />
</div>
<p>
    Closed between <time datetime="2015-12-24">24th of December</time> and <time datetime="2015-12-26">26th of December</time>.
</p>
<div property="openingHoursSpecification" typeof="OpeningHoursSpecification">
    <meta content="10:00:00" property="opens" />
    <meta content="18:00:00" property="closes" />
    <meta content="2015-12-27" property="validFrom" />
</div>
```

Of course this solution is also flawed:

1. It requires potentially a lot of duplicate markup.
2. It relies heavily on using "invisible" `meta` elements instead of marking up visible data which is what Google recommends.

So which one of these solutions is best/least incorrect? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you have a specific Google Rich Snippet (or similar feature) in mind? I can’t find any where they claim to support opening hours at all.

Comment: I was under the impression that Rich Snippets supported opening hours for businesses. I see it all the time when searching for specific businesses. And Google has examples of using opening hours on its Google Developers website: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/business-location-pages/schema.org-examples

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I wonder why they don’t put this (also) into their [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/) section. And unfortunately they don’t document which properties are supported, they merely give some examples :/

Answer (score 1):

As you said there is an open issue on schema.org for this,  so you may be better attempting your own solutions and using trial-and-error to see if google picks it up correct. I would use solution 2. because it gives closed hours and seems clearest, this sounded similar to the suggested solution  from the schema.org thread https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/240#issuecomment-95458846

The  aren't an issue - machine readable dates are one of the exceptions when considering use of **Non-visible and machine-radable data**, according to [google's policies](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies) this can include dates, prices, currencies, etc.

Although the official documentation from google states it may take months to pick up changes, I've found Fetch-As-Google and a 2-3 day wait at the most works for both microdata and JSON-LD, eg in the [long list of comments on a schema.org microdata question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290616/aggregate-rating-google-rich-snippet-not-working/32385289#32385289) you can see the original poster tries several different changes a few days apart with 3 days between the last change and google picking it up.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer this solution, because it avoids any redundance, is clear and valid:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Store">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Middle of Nowhere Foods</h1>
  <h2>Opening hours</h2>
    <p>Normally open <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 09:00-14:00">daily 9am-2pm</time> except on:</p>
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
      <span itemprop="validFrom" content="2013-12-24">24 December 2013</span> and
      <span itemprop="validThrough" content="2013-12-25">25 December 2013</span>:
      <span itemprop="opens" content="09:00">9am</span>-<span itemprop="closes" content="11:00">11am</span></li>
    <li itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
      <span itemprop="validFrom" content="2014-01-01">1st January 2014</span>
      <span itemprop="validThrough" content="2014-01-01"></span>:
      <span itemprop="opens" content="12:00">Noon</span>-<span itemprop="closes" content="14:00">2pm</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: With all due respect this answer doesn't at all address the problem posed in the question. I know I can use openingHoursSpecification to communicate alternative hours when the business is open. What I want to do as well is specify dates when the business is closed for the whole day regardless of the regular opening hours. Many businesses have holiday periods so I was surprised to see that this was not addressed in Schema.org vocabulary or for that matter in the GoodRelations vocabulary from which OpeningHoursSpecification comes from.

Comment: @ST17 The bottlenecks are that Schema.org-format doesn't allow setting of datetime durations, like they are described here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp, under Duration Data Type. And there isn't a Schema.org property like "closed". So one is forced to use opens=00:00 closes=00:00

Comment: Note that this is *not* valid HTML5+Microdata, as the `time` element’s `datetime` attribute [may not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28089509/1591669) contain a value like "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 09:00-14:00", and the `span` element [may not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) have a `content` attribute.