# How to specify "closed" for a day in OpeningHoursSpecification?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

```
{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
        "Sunday"
    ],
    "Hours": "Closed"
}
```

I get the following error:

> Closed (The property Hours is not recognized by Google for an object of type OpeningHoursSpecification.)

This is how i am doing a weekday

```
  {
        "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
        "dayOfWeek": [
            "Friday"
        ],
        "Hours" :"10:00 - 17:30"
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to represent closed days (holidays) using Schema.org vocabulary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85103/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-closed-days-holidays-using-schema-org-vocabu)

Comment: Where is `Hours` coming from? If it were a property, it would have to be lowercase `hours`, but this isn’t a valid Schema.org property (https://schema.org/hours gives a 404 error).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to represent closed days (holidays) using Schema.org vocabulary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85103/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-closed-days-holidays-using-schema-org-vocabu)

Comment: I am not trying to do Holiday I have looked at the links you have posted @StephenOstermiller and Patrick-mevzek

Comment: @unor I am not sure what is the best way to show the time. I don't want to do opens and close

Comment: @jibingeorge: My question was where you got this `Hours`/`hours` property from, as it’s not coming from Schema.org. Did you invent it yourself, or did you find/read about it somewhere?

Comment: @unor I didn't look at the Schema.org, I assumed i  could pass any name but now i know i shoudln't

Answer (score 3):

Maybe i don't understand exactly your purposes, but as stated in the `Schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification` documentation

> The place is open if the opens property is specified, and closed otherwise.

According to this i would set only opening times by implication of `closed is when not open`.

**PS** to go into the case rised by @StephenOstermiller: to deal with exceptions like holidays there is a following standard-conform workaround:

- The [`Date` format, which is ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), allows setup of durations, time intervals and repeating intervals and, further, combinations of date and time.
- These data can be implemented by `validFrom / validThrough`

Comment: How about the case where you would normally be open on Mondays but you have to specify a Monday holiday where you would be closed?

Comment: so monday i open 9-5 for sunday what do i put i dont open on sundays

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, i have had such case - to get it the first time was veeeery tricky for me. Finally i've got a solution using validity (validFrom validThrough) and the date, which allows repeatable dates too.

Comment: @jibingeorge - for sunday - just nothing. Put only: open monday-saturday 9-17.

Comment: Is there any way to indicate something like "closed on Easter" for a holiday with varying date?

Answer (score 2):

From [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business#business-hours) (click on "All-day hours" tab)

> To show a business is closed all day, set both opens and closes
> properties to "00:00"

```
"openingHoursSpecification": [
  {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
    "opens": "00:00",
    "closes": "00:00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Full Example, of different hours of business in 24Hour format, including closed on Sundays.

```
    "openingHoursSpecification": [
    {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
    "opens": "09:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Tuesday",
    "opens": "09:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
    "opens": "11:00",
    "closes": "20:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "opens": "09:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
  },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Friday",
    "opens": "09:00",
    "closes": "17:00"
   },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
    "opens": "09:30",
    "closes": "16:00"
   },{
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
    "opens": "00:00",
    "closes": "00:00"
  }
],
```